# need help understanding aspects of php objects

Tags: php, class, object

i am new to php and is in need of some help to understand the aspects of php objects which i do not get. In class a i have made class b and c which extends a, but what i want to do is acess the public letters variable in class a from class c so in can get ot the function testb() from class c.

Any help is much appreciated guys

```
   <?php

    class a {
        public $letters;
        function __construct() {
            $this->letters->b = new b();
            $this->letters->c = new c();
        }
    }   

    class b extends a {
        function __construct() {
            echo "hello world from b ";
        }

        private function testb() {
            echo "testing from b";
        }
    }

    class c extends a {
        function __construct() {
            echo "hello world from c ";
            $this->letters->b->testb();
        }
    }


    $a = new a();

?>
```

the following script echos our "hello world from b" and "hello world from c" but it does not print out "testing from b"...

Comment: why would you extend a class (i'm talkin about c extends a) if you are goind to overwrite all it's contents? :)

Answer (score 2):

A gotcha of PHP Objects is that Inheritance is fudged (just a bit).. The constructor of a parent object is not implicitly called when you instantiate one of it's child objects.  Instead you must explicitly call the Parent Object's constructor.

```
class b extends a {
...
    public __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        echo("Hello From B!");
    }
...
}
```

In your Class `c` constructor, `$this->letters` is not an object and has not been initialized since the `a` constructor has not been called.

If you're just playing around with objects, then ignore this part, but you're close to getting a circular hierarchy.  If you add the changes that I suggested, I believe your code will explode if you try to instantiate either a B or a C object directly.

Comment: You're right about what you said - the constructor of parent object isn't explicitly called. However, why is it fudged? It's absolutely logical. You're extending something. Why would you enforce parent constructor being called if you can choose whether it's called or not? Anyway, +1 from me because you were the only one who noticed what was wrong (other authors wisely edited their posts afterwards).

Comment: The idea behind inheritance is that if I have a B object extending an A object is that the B object is also an A object.  All other languages I can think of enforce this implicitly.  Anyway, thats my 2 cents.

Comment: @watcher The parent constructor is not called because the child class has a constructor defined that replaces the parent constructor like with any other method. Without the constructor in class B, the constructor in class A would be called automatically when you create a B object.

Comment: @jeroen - I think watcher knows that. @watcher - don't you think that's absolutely wrong? What if parent constructor lacks functionality that I require for my extended class but every other function in parent class does exactly what I want? Doesn't it seem wrong that I am *forced* to call the parent constructor where I can have the liberty of *choosing* whether I want it or not? If all other languages implement it like that (which isn't true), that does not immediately mean that it's the correct choice, hence I don't really agree PHP's way is "fudged". It's more flexible.

Comment: @Michael I agree it is more flexible, I'm thinking more from a hypothetical point of view.  If I have a Class Vehicle and a Class Car which Extends Vehicle then the constructor of Vehicle should only do what should be done to initialize a General Vehicle.  Since a Car is a vehicle it _should_ be constructed the same way as any general vehicle, with added complexity of however you want to construct the car.  It's just my opinion that if a superclass constructor is not called, then the whole notion of Inheritance is not truly being followed, so why are you extending the class in the first place?

Comment: Well, if your `class car` hasn't got a constructor of its own - the parent one will be called. If it has it's own constructor, you can *still* call parent constructor AND your own or choose whether you want your own overriding parent one completely. I really see no flaw in inheritance here, you have more options available :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't call `testb` from within the class `c` is that the method signature of `testb` declares it as `private` - meaning it can only be accessed within `b` instances. Change the visibility to default (no modifier) or `public`.

E.g.:

```
function testb() {
    echo "testing from b";
}
```

Or:

```
public function testb() {
    echo "testing from b";
}
```

Edit:

The problem is that you haven't called the super constructor from the constructor of c - the value of `$this->b` is therefore not initialised. Change the constructor of c to:

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    echo "hello world from c ";
    $this->letters->b->testb();
}
```

Unfortunately, though, this will create an infinite loop where the constructor of `a` is instantiating `c` and the constructor of `c` is calling up to the constructor of `a`. Why do your letter classes even extend one another?

You also need to change the visibility of `testb` within the `b` class.

Comment: no good, i tried that before and it didnt work which is why i came here, i just var_dumped it and it came back null.. :/

Comment: Amended my answer with more problems I spotted.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you extend class **c** from **b** you can call the method otherwise not as you are extending it from class a not from c..

Comment: give me a min to run a quick test

Comment: no good, i tried that before and it didnt work which is why i came here, i just var_dumped it and it came back null.. :/

Answer (score 0):

In your class `a` you are constructing a new object of class `c`.

This new object has no property `$this->letters->b`, it just has an uninitialized property `$this->letters`.

Note that the new object inherits the property `$letters` from the class it extends, but it does not inherit any values of an instantiated `a` object. So there is no `$this->letters->b` and no function `$this->letters->b->testb()` to call.

Answer (score -1):

"c" extends "a" and doesn't inherit "b"s method

your example will return

> Fatal error: Call to a member function
>   testb() on a non-object

for

> $this->letters->b->testb();